# How to cast string to byte like object

Tags: python, binary, file-manipulation

I am trying to make a python script that encodes any file into a txt file. So far I can encode an input file into a txt file that contains the original files name, content and a sha hash for integrity checking (if you wish I can dump the code so far here).
Currently, I just make a standard list and dump said list into a txt file.
However, when reading from the list I get strings, but have no way of **casting** the string into a "byte like object", and a Google search only shows conversion (cast and convert are different) methods.
Is there any way to cast the string in the way you can do `str(variable)`?

Also, on a side note: does "rb" include metadata, title, etc?

Comment: If your `variable` is a text string object, you can encode it with your preferred encoding like `variable.encode("utf-8")` and get a `bytes` object.

Comment: @progmatico the problem is that when I read a file I cast it into a string to write it to the other file. I get a text document with the bytes like object casted to a string. I don't need to encode, I need to cast.

Comment: Python has no casts in the `C` sense. You just create a new object instance of a type from some data of different (or same) type. I think you just need to read the binary source as binary, build a string with the hex representation of each byte read, concatenate whatever metadata you want and write result as a text file. Reverse the operations to recover the original file.